# take everything unless it sees foo

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

Learning Regex.

I want to match everything unless it sees `foo`.

**Input:**

```
take everything 1 foo take everything 2 foo take everything 3
take everything 4
```

**Expect:**

```
match 1 : `take everything 1 `
match 2 : ` take everything 2 `
match 3 : ` take everything 3 `
match 4 : `take everything 4`
```

**Attempt:**

1. `([^foo]*)` http://regex101.com/r/rT0wU0/1

   Result:

   match 1            : `take everything 1`

   match 2-4, 6-8, 10 :

   match 5            : `take everything 2`

   match 9            : `take everything 3 take everything 4`
2. `(.*(?!foo))` http://regex101.com/r/hL4gP7/1

   Result:

   match 1            : `take everything 1 foo take everything 2 foo take everything 3`

   match 2, 3         :

   match 4            : `take everything 4`

Please enlighten me.

Comment: probably add some f or o into your string to see why the first one fails? for the second one, I'd try `.*?` instead of `.*` (just a guess, without having tested it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a word boundary `\b` in conjunction with a Negative Lookahead.

```
\b(?:(?!foo).)+
```

Example:

```
String s = @"take everything 1 foo take everything 2 foo take everything 3
take everything 4";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(s, @"\b(?:(?!foo).)+"))
         Console.WriteLine(m.Value.Trim());
```

Output

```
take everything 1
take everything 2
take everything 3
take everything 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex,

```
(?<=foo|^)(.*?)(?=foo|$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rT0wU0/3)

- `(?<=foo|^)` Lookafter `foo` or the start of the line.
- `(.*?)` Matches everything upto the string `foo` or end of the line.

Comment: sorry I missed the `m` multiline

Comment: yep, you need to add `m` modifier to make regex to work on multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = @"take everything 1 foo take everything 2 foo take everything 3
take everything 4";

var result = Regex.Matches(input, @"(.+?)((?>foo)|(?>$))", RegexOptions.Multiline)
                    .Cast<Match>()
                    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value.Trim())
                    .ToList();
```

[image]